# Ignore temporary files or suppress "Invalid Exclude: filename. File not found." message from Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift-package-manager

I have a Swift Package which consists only of C files. It builds and works great as part of my iOS app. However, the directory also contains a `Makefile` and a simple REPL to use for adhoc development and testing. Accordingly, there will often, but not always, be `.o` files, as well as support files like `tags` during active development.

I use the SPM `Package { targets: [.target( exclude ...` setting to make sure those files are never included while building the app which includes this package. However, it means that in a "clean" environment like a CI machine there will be build messages like:

```
Invalid Exclude '..../Packages/SchemeC/Sources/SchemeC/s7repl.o': File not found.
Invalid Exclude '..../Packages/SchemeC/Sources/SchemeC/s7sqlite.o': File not found.
Invalid Exclude '..../Packages/SchemeC/Sources/SchemeC/s7.o': File not found.
Invalid Exclude '.../Packages/SchemeC/Sources/SchemeC/TAGS.scheme': File not found.
```

Is there a way to mark a file as "Ignore" for Swift Package Manager? *(I.e. similar to including a file in `.gitignore`?)*

Comment: Can you put them into a Folder and exclude that folder instead?

Comment: @Larme It's not simple to put them into a folder unfortunately. Well, not without complicating the Makefile. I'm already using symlinks with header files to juggle happiness between SPM default expectations and standard C defaults. That said, I might give it a try ... thanks!